# Overwriting a list in a two for loop function (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

So let's consider that I have the following array:

```
arr1 = [[1,1],[2,1]]
```

Now, I construct the following function:

```
def func(mylist):                                                                                                                                             
    print(mylist)                                                                                                                                             
    List = list(mylist)                                                                                                                                       
    for i in range(2):                                                                                                                                        
        for j in range(2):                                                                                                                                    
            List[i][j]=0                                                                                                                                      
    print mylist                                                                                                                                              
    print List                                                                                                                                                
    return mylist
```

Then, when I call my function on my arr1, the initial array is modified (mylist).
This is really strange behaviour, because I'm doing a copy of mylist and only
modifying the copied array List. Anyone can explain to me what is happening?

Comment: `list()` only creates a shallow copy, use `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: your indentation and naming is all over the place

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary Ok, thanks. That fixes the problem. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: I don't know why people downvoted so furiously on this one, formatting on SO is not so obvious to new-comers.

Comment: Thanks by the way for the formatting part. I'll try to do better next time ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why people downvoted this questions, as is quite valid.

Now, consider this:

```
>>> mylist1 = [(1,2), (3,4)]
>>> mylist2 = list(mylist1)

>>> mylist1
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> mylist2
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]

>>> mylist2[0] = (0, 0)

>>> mylist1
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
>>> mylist2
[(0, 0), (3, 4)]
```

As you can see, the `list()` creates a copy of the list, but this copy is not a "deep" copy and if the list contains mutable objects (lists, dictionaries, or objects) the copy will just copy the reference to those objects instead of the content on them. For example:

```
>>> mylist1 = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> mylist2 = list(mylist1)
>>> mylist2[0][0] = 0
>>> mylist2
[[0, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> mylist1
[[0, 2], [3, 4]]
```

That is because the reference to the first element list got copied to the new list, not it's content or a full copy of the list, it still is the same list.

As already mentioned, use `copy.deepcopy`:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy

You can read there:

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

Another option for your special case is to use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> mylist1 = [[1,2], [3,4]]
>>> mylist2 = [list(elem) for elem in mylist1] # < This one
>>> mylist1
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> mylist2
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> mylist2[0][0] = 0
>>> mylist1
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> mylist2
[[0, 2], [3, 4]]
```

This will also copy the list that are elements.